# cannot use PHP in our CMS but i want to add PHP tag to it

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe, content-management-system

I'm using adobe business catalyst to build a site. and it doesn't allow to use PHP and I can use just HTML,CSS,Javascript. and I need to add PHP API to my site. but directly, I can't do that. Is there anyway to do that like using iframes ?

Comment: Didn't you already answer your own question?

Comment: but not sure how to iframe to it. PHP tag into another PHP enabled server and that again back to my CMS using Iframe? is it

Comment: Should be easy to test?

Answer (score 1):

PHP is a server side programming language. So just adding php tags to your CMS content absolutely does nothing.

Of course you could deploy some php code somewhere else and then use an iframe to display that page within your content in your cms.

Or, if you have control over the http headers of whatever php you want to serve from another server, you could use AJAX to get the information. Note that using AJAX to grab information from another server requires you to use CORS to bypass the security limitations of Javascript (same origin policy).

If all this does not ring a bell, you probably should not do it.